# Calculate the number of reservations for 1 day

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm stuck on the calculation of the number of reservations made during the day. People can book up to 4 covers, the capacity of the restaurant is 40 covers. I can't check to see if there's room left. I have a sql query to retrieve the reservations for the day, then I block on the reservations for the days to retrieve the number of covers for each reservation. How do I add the number of covers for all the reservations for the day? I'm going to check this on the backend side with nodejs and express js.

Thank you in advance for your help

```
exports.createReservation = (req,res)=>{

const {numeroReservation, id_user, idBoutique, horaire, dateReservation, nombreCouverts} = req.body;

 connection.query(reservation.getAllReservationByIdBoutiqueDateReservation,[idBoutique,dateReservation],(error,result)=>{
   for(var i =0,len = result.length; i< len; i++){
            const test = result[i].nombreCouverts * result[i].nombreCouverts
             console.log(test)
             
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: You must be saving the status for the remaining covers? The idea is once the user starts to book and complete the booking then you should reduce the number of covers for that particular day. Each time any users wanted to book the covers make sure you left with covers by checking the remaining numbers. You should create a table for everyday covers. Even in future it will help you to check how many covers were used every day

Comment: Thank you for response @ApoorvaChikara , I think I'm going to create another table with the date and number of covers as columns. Then retrieve this number of covers before each reservation, then update the covers. Because I don't see how to manage this from the reservation table

Comment: Yes, You should and based on the value for current date you can manage your reservation.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara I did as I said in my previous post and it worked. Thank you for the time you gave me :)